# Small input, large output?

Tags: c++

I have a question about this short code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream fout("hps.out");
    ifstream fin("hps.in");
    int N;
    fin >> N;
    int a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int x, y;
        fin >> x;
        fin >> y;

        if (x == 1 && y == 2) {
            a1++;
        }
        if (x == 1 && y == 3) {
            a2++;
        }
        if (x == 2 && y == 1) {
            b1++;
        }
        if (x == 2 && y == 3) {
            b2++;
        }
        if (x == 3 && y == 1) {
            c1++;
        }
        if (x == 3 && y == 2) {
            c2++;
        }
    } 
    fout << a1 << " " << a2 << " " << b1 << " " << b2 << " " << c1 << " " << 
c2 << " " << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

So here's the input:

```
5
1 2
2 2
1 3
1 1
3 2
```

and here is the output:

32768 4197767 0 616536480 0 1

what I want to do is count the number of pairs of (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,3), (3,1) and (3,3), and store these values in the variables a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2. However for some reason I am getting these gigantic numbers and I don't understand why. Is something overflowing?

The statement for this problem is actually USACO Bronze Janurary #2:

http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=688

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You haven't initialized `a1, a2, b1, b2, c1`. They hold garbage values at the time you are  incrementing them.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm pretty new at coding

Comment: Oh, so the statement int a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 = 0; is not enough? Ah I see now. Thanks!

Comment: You only initialise `c2 = 0;`, all the other variables are uninitialised and will just take whatever value is in memory at the time. Initialising all your variables to `0` will solve your issue

Comment: `int a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 = 0;` --> `int a1=0, a2=0, b1=0, b2=0, c1=0, c2 = 0;`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it _was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 2):

Problem lies with this line:

```
int a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 = 0;
```

This only initializes c2 with a zero. The rest hold garbage values.
You need to do `= 0` for each variable.